# static method vs instance method vs lambda

Tags: java

Whenever I need to define local helper methods in a class, I find myself wondering how exactly I should define them. The following three options seem interchangeable to me. Which one is best (objectively) and why?
**I found several threads about static vs instance methods, but none which also mentioned local lambda's:

```
private void ifEmpty(Collection c) {
    if(c.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException();
}

private static void ifEmpty(Collection c) {
    if(c.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException();
}

private Consumer<Collection> ifEmpty = (c) -> {if(c.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException();};
```

Comment: I would use none, since all of them are using a raw `List`.

Comment: Valid point(I'll update). Which one would you use if list would be replaced by collection?

Comment: still none, still raw.

Comment: Could you tell me a better type to use? I cannot come up with one.

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)